# driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS) does not working

Tags: java, selenium, wait

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The above implicity wait code is not working for me on Google chrome. I have tried with selenium 2.47 and 2.53.1

Comment: how do you know that it is not working ? what is the error you are seeing?

Comment: If I change the seconds to 60, In application it is not waiting for 60 seconds. I am not getting any error. If I use Thread.sleep(60) it works fine.

Comment: Make sure you are dealing with one driver object.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should read up on what implicit wait actually does and how it works.

http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits

It's not something that you call to wait for 10 seconds, it only comes into play when an element that is being searched for is not available... *then* the implicit wait is triggered and that element is polled up to the 10s. If the element is already there, then there is no wait time. `Thread.sleep()` pauses execution no matter what but is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or elements **(if) they are not immediately available**. The default setting is 0. Once set, the implicit wait is set for the life of the WebDriver object instance.