# Automation waits for the webpage to load for 10 minutes when i have given wait time as 10 seconds

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, implicitwait

I have a java selenium project .I have used implicit wait of 10 seconds using

```java
driver.manage()
    .timeouts()
    .implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Still the automation scripts wait for 10 minutes for the webpage to load.
[Here is the image that will be there 10 minutes and then it will fail.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8wtX.png)

What is the possible reason for it?

Comment: take a look at the answer of JeffC at this question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41143520/driver-manage-timeouts-implicitlywait10-timeunit-seconds-does-not-working

and maybe this question helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43247670/limiting-the-timeout-period-for-selenium-findelement?rq=1

Comment: I am using implicit-wait to wait for element presence on page, but after 10 seconds when the element doesnt show up the test case should fail. This happens after 10 minutes.

Comment: check what is your page load timeout?

Comment: @Murthi how to Check the page load timeout? Using any code or what? The page have some issue it never loads actually. So i wanted each test case to fail,instead each test case is getting failed after 10 minutes excatly

Comment: AndiCover's answer may help you.

Comment: Thank-you @Murthi for looking into it. PageLoadTimeout was the missing line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments you need to set the page load timeout as well. The implicit wait timeout does not have any effect in this case. Try following line:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

In Selenium you have three different timeouts which all have different default values. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30121876/7450414) answer which IMHO explains them quite good.

Comment: Thank-you @AndiCover ,this was something which i wasn't aware about.